# django_allauth socialaccount providers disappeared

Tags: django-allauth

I had working social providers few weeks/months ago, but it is not working anymore. I checked docs and still do not know what am I missing. I think it stopped working after I upgraded django to 1.8 (changed template context processors in settings.py, ...)  I had google, facebook and twitter working.
Here is my settings.py regarding allauth:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.core.context_processors.media",
                "django.core.context_processors.static",
                "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",

                # Required by allauth template tags
                'django.template.context_processors.request',

                #controller context processors (portfolios)
                "controller.context_processors.portfolio_processor",
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

#allauth settings
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 3
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 5
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {
    'facebook':
       {'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False},
    'google':
        { 'SCOPE': ['profile', 'email'],
          'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'access_type': 'online' } }
    }

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #library folder
    'lib',

    #extra apps
    'django_crontab',

    #search
    'haystack',

    #apps
    'stocks',
    'portfolio',
    'watcher',
    'suggestion',
    #'broker',

    #allauth
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'loginas',

    #allauth providers
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',

    #bootstrap
    'bootstrap3',
    'bootstrap3_datetime',

    #admin
    'django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig',
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    #'django.contrib.admindocs',

    'debug_toolbar',
)
```

Of cource I have set up twitter, facebook and google in social applications in admin.
In login.html I incude providers like this:

```
    {% if socialaccount.providers  %}
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
      <!--
      This is the raw "real" HTML that facebook recommends.
      Leaving here for reference.

      <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
      -->

      <div class="socialaccount_ballot">
        <ul class="socialaccount_providers list-unstyled">
          {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %}
        </ul>

        <div class="login-or" style="text-align: center">{% trans 'or' %}</div>
      </div>

      {% include "socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html" %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

And then in `socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html`:

```
{% load socialaccount %}

{% for provider in socialaccount.providers %}
{% if provider.id == "openid" %}
{% for brand in provider.get_brands %}
<li>
  <a title="{{brand.name}}"
     class="socialaccount_provider {{provider.id}} {{brand.id}}"
     href="{% provider_login_url provider.id openid=brand.openid_url process=process %}"
     >{{brand.name}}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<li style="text-align: center;">
  <a title="{{provider.name}}" class="socialaccount_provider {{provider.id}}"
     href="{% provider_login_url provider.id process=process scope=scope auth_params=auth_params %}">{{provider.name}}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

when I try to print soccialaccount, it's blank/None:

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{{socialaccount}}
```

What am I missing? I am using django 1.8 and allauth=0.23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were changes from 0.21, so check what happens when you do

```
{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}
{{ socialaccount_providers  }}
```